# Generator for Keras/Tensorflow training includes sqlite3 connection that yields threading related error

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, keras

**Summary: I wrote a generator that sometimes `yields` with an open `sqlite3` connection. However, I do not enable multithreading. Nonetheless I got an error indicating that my sqlite3 db connection was being accessed by more than one thread. What to do?**

I was attempting to train a model like so:

```
model3.fit_generator(train_gen3, round(TOTAL_SIZE * (1 - VALID_PCT) / BATCH_SIZE), 
                epochs = 1, verbose = 1, 
                validation_data = valid_gen3, validation_steps = round(TOTAL_SIZE * VALID_PCT / BATCH_SIZE))
```

Notice that I left the default `use_multiprocessing` setting, which means it ought to be set to false per the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/). However, at the end of my first epoch of training, this error was spit out:

`sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 140487084246784 and this is thread id 140468885124864`

Within my generator I do open a `sqlite3` connection like so:

```
 with sqlite3.connect(self.data_dir + f) as conn:
                            results = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl")
                            rows = results.fetchall()
                            df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
...

                                if len(x_return_list) == batch_size:
                                    yield (np.array(x_return_list), np.array(y_return_list))
                                    x_return_list = []
                                    y_return_list = []
```

So I do yield with an open `sqlite3` connection, but I thought this should not be a problem given that I have not enabled any form of threading/multiprocessing. What is going on here, and what is the best workaround?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have the same issue

Comment: @GuillaumeA In my case I realized I was leaving the SQLite connection to the db open when in fact I could already just have the data frame and not need to keep the connection open. But my best guess is that TF is multithreaded running the generator so there may be no safe solution that involves keeping the sqlite file open.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I ended up opening a new connection at each iteration of the generator as SQLite connection is not pickable.

Comment: @GuillaumeA is there any performance disadvantage with this approach?